# Can I load a single package from a different archive?

Tags: package, package-repositories

For my main package loading, I want to use `melpa-stable`. There's at least one package (`dash`) that I know breaks my config if I use the `melpa` version. That's fine - I've no problem using `melpa-stable` as my default archive.

But there are some packages I need to get from `melpa` - specifically `sublime-themes`. Obviously I could download that package manually and install it somewhere in my load-path, but I'd prefer to use the package manager (and I'd *also* like to do so from elisp, so I can have my `init.el` install it if it's not present, for when I go to a new machine).

Is it possible to say "use this archive for this package, but don't use it for other packages"?

Comment: You can add melpa to your list of archives but give it a priority of -100 so it will not be used automatically

Comment: Thanks. I just found this myself. I believe this is a new feature in Emacs 25.1, but that's fine for me as I don't expect to be using older versions with my config.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a feature in Emacs 25.1 that does what I want, by allowing you to set priorities for the archives you specify. So you can say

```
(setq package-archive-priorities
      '(("melpa-stable" . 20)
        ("marmalade" . 20)
        ("gnu" . 10)
        ("melpa" . 0)))
```

This will then install packages from the highest-priority archive they are available in. So with the above, `melpa` will only be used if a package can't be found in any of the other archives.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can! It is called pinning. If you use `use-package` its as easy as

```
(use-package sublime-themes
       :ensure t
       :pin melpa-stable)
```

otherwise you can set `package-pinned-packages` to `((sublime-themes . "melpa-stable"))` more info can be found [here](http://www.lonecpluspluscoder.com/2014/11/25/using-elpa-pinned-packages-gnu-emacs-24-4/)

Comment: Isn't that the wrong way round? I want to use melpa (not stable) *only* for sublime-themes, but not for any other packages. With pinning, wouldn't I need melpa in my archive list and pin everything *except* sublime-themes? Or am I missing something?

Comment: Ooooh yes I had mis-read my bad. The reason that normally melpa is prioritized is that the package number is usually greater than the melpa-stable package number